# Missing parts after parsing and processing a very large XML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, sax

I have to parse and modify a 22.2MB XML file (a wordpress export).
The problem is after parsing, the last part of the file is always missing, but I can't really figure out why.

I've tried using the saxerator gem, but it does not seem to solve my problem

Here I'm just trying to get all the `<item>` from the input file and display them in an output file:

```
class SaxImport
  def initialize input_file, output_file
    f = File.read(input_file, File.size(input_file))

    xml_data = Saxerator.parser(f) do |config|
      config.output_type = :xml
    end

    category_fr_list = {}
    items = []

    output = File.open output_file, "w"

    xml_data.for_tag(:item).reverse_each do |item|
      output << item.to_xml
    end

    output.close
  end
end

import_en = SaxImport.new 'weekly.xml', 'weekly.processed.xml'
```

Comment: Is it possible you have an encoding error? Can you isolate parts of the XML to process separately so you can test each part to find if it is a size issue or a content one? Is the result the same if you switch roughly the first half of the file with the last half? If the content is the problem, you should be able to drill down in your file's hierarchy to find which part of the 22.2Mb causes the problem.

Comment: For parsing `XML` I would always recommend [`nokogiri`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) it is immensely powerful and very fast. I also use [`builder`](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) on occasion to generate `XML` files it is also very flexible and fairly easy to grasp the basics.

Comment: Also for things like this providing a simplified example of the `XML` will get you a lot more answers.

Comment: You're not using Nokogiri, so why is this tagged as a Nokogiri question? Also, we can't help you much without a clue what your XML looks like. 22MB isn't huge these days and should easily be handled on most machines, allowing you to use a DOM-based parser for convenience. You *can* use a SAX-based one, and it might be smart if your file size is going to be larger than available memory. Finally, using `File.read` totally negates the advantages of a SAX parser since you're reading the entire file into memory, rather than letting the parser stream it.

Comment: Instead of `File.read(input_file, File.size(input_file))` use `File.read(input_file)`. It does the same thing.

Comment: So eventually the issue came from a corrupt XML. I could not find the error with Nokogiri. But I eventually figured it out with xmllint.

Comment: After knocking my head against the wall for 6 hours! XmlLint showed me that there is a tiny weird character in one field in certain items causing them to be skipped. Damn, that took a while. Thanks m0g.